# paginating random list sql

Tags: php, sql

Im working in a basic pagination list where I need all the results be retrieved ramdomly

this is why I use

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE 1
 ORDER BY rand()
```

It works well until I need to paginate it...

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE 1
 ORDER BY rand()
 LIMIT $offset, $recordsperPage
```

How do I retrieve the whole list in random order, but when paginated, every page do not repeat the prior random words?

Comment: Isn't that the meaning of randomness, that you will not receive the same data on two following calls?

Comment: @NicoHaase No actually it means the opposite. Think of a rolling a dice. It is random but that does not mean it does not repeat.

Comment: I think if you do not want repetition, you will need to keep track of items already seen and keep passing that to your query and filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a consistent seed to the [`rand()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) call, you'll get the same sequence. You might use something derived from the date, for example, to give the same results for the day, or generate some other random seed from PHP and save it in the session, to give the same results only for a given visitor.